Runnig React Native app results in missing module "perf_hooks"
I have problems running my React Native app. I had a working version, that I could build and run on iOS and Android. After changing some code in some components, I was unable to run the app on both Systems. Metro throws the following error message:
error: Error: Unable to resolve module perf_hooks from 
/Users/xxxxxx/AppProjects/AppName/node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js: 
perf_hooks could not be found within the project or in these directories:
node_modules
 5 | });
 6 | exports.runCLI = runCLI;
 7 | function _perf_hooks() {
   |           ^
 8 |   const data = require('perf_hooks');
 9 |   _perf_hooks = function () {
10 |     return data;
at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/xxxxxx/AppProjects/AppName/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:139:15)
at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/xxxxxx/AppProjects/AppName/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:277:43)
at Object.resolve (/Users/xxxxxx/AppProjects/AppName/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:169:21)
at Graph._resolveDependencies (/Users/xxxxxx/AppProjects/AppName/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:473:35)
at Graph._processModule (/Users/xxxxxx/AppProjects/AppName/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:261:38)
at async Graph._addDependency (/Users/xxxxxx/AppProjects/AppName/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:372:20)
at async Promise.all (index 1)
at async Graph._processModule (/Users/xxxxxx/AppProjects/AppName/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:322:5)
at async Graph._addDependency (/Users/xxxxxx/AppProjects/AppName/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:372:20)
at async Promise.all (index 0)

I tried multiple thing like updating dependencies und updating node as well as npm, but nothing worked. I created a testfile, that just requires this module, but that works without trowing an error. Needless to say, that I reinstalled all node modules and wiped the build cache multiple times. Still the error persists.
Output of npx react-native info:
System:
  OS: macOS 14.1.1
  CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M1 Pro
  Memory: 785.77 MB / 32.00 GB
  Shell:
    version: "5.9"
    path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 22.12.0
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v22.12.0/bin/node
  Yarn: Not Found
  npm:
    version: 10.9.0
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v22.12.0/bin/npm
  Watchman:
    version: 2024.12.02.00
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
  CocoaPods:
    version: 1.15.2
    path: /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 23.0
      - iOS 17.0
      - macOS 14.0
      - tvOS 17.0
      - watchOS 10.0
  Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 2023.3 AI-233.14808.21.2331.11709847
  Xcode:
    version: 15.0.1/15A507
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
  Java:
    version: 17.0.13
    path: /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17/bin/javac
  Ruby:
    version: 2.6.10
    path: /usr/bin/ruby
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
    installed: 18.2.0
    wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
    installed: 0.72.5
    wanted: 0.72.5
  react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false

